# AspectFill - clip only one side

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like only the bottom part of the image to get clipped, is that possible? Currently, equal portions of the image get clipped at the top and at the bottom.

I tried setting `VerticalOptions` to `Start`, but had no success.

[image]

The red rectangles represent the screen and the blue rectangles represent the image that needs clipping. The top figure shows the current state and the bottom figure the desired state.

Comment: I suggest you to try adding a margin-top property to the image in order to push it down to your desired position. You also may want to take a look to absolute layout to see if you can manually set its position a little bit down to create the effect you want.

Comment: @SergioAMG Margin is applied after the clipping occurs. For the same reason, nothing with absolute layout comes to my mind.

Comment: Could you put it in a scrollview and disable scrolling?

Comment: @TaylorD that does indeed work, but I am afraid of the two following things 1) performance 2) possible issues this could cause to controls rendered on top of this. The image I am scaling is the background so often there will be a `ListView`/`CollectionView` on top of it. Do you know whether either of the two are actual risks or I worry needlessly?

Comment: @TaylorD also to clarify, nothing other than the image will be a child of the `ScrollView`, only rendered on top of it.

Comment: So its just being used as a background image. Ok. Yeah it could have some weird side effects if UI isn't structured right, but a Grid with controls being overlapped on top should work fine. Without doing it this method, I'm not sure how to do it. This is just what popped into my head right away when I saw the post.